# Адаптивность, @media-запросы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь написать адаптивность сайта с помощью @media-запросов. Использовать дополнительные библиотеки и фреймворки, кроме Bootstrap4 крайне нежелательно. Проблема заключается в определении устройства по пикселям (max- и min-width). Из-за плотности точек на моём телефоне гороздо больше пикселей, чем на ноутбуке, и поэтому сайт выводится некорректно. Как ещё можно определить устройство-просмотрщик?

Comment: А `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` не подойдёт?

Comment: Не, по умолчанию стоит. Результатов нету((

Comment: Крайне странно, думаю стоит ещё разок проверить правильно ли прописано. Но если интересуют `@media` запросы, то можно проверить `dpi` при помощи [resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution) или соотношение сторон при помощи [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)

Comment: `@media handheld` - тоже пробовал ?

Comment: Ein, напишите Ваш ответ в Ответ, а я Вам баллов накину. Помогло)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Но если обходиться только медиа запросами, то можно проверить `dpi` при помощи [resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution) или соотношение сторон при помощи [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)